Getting SQL exception data is null, this method or property cannot be called on null values
I have a C# application in which I am trying to fetch details from a SQL Server database. This database contains null values, and I want to handle these in the C# application.
My table schema is like this:

This is my HomeController:
using Device_Migration_Admin_Portal.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace Device_Migration_Admin_Portal.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly DeviceDbContext _context;
 
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, DeviceDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }
 
        // Existing Index action
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var devices = await _context.DeviceMigrationStatus.ToListAsync();
            var sanitizedDevices = devices.Select(d => new DeviceMigrationStatus
            {
                DeviceSerial = d.DeviceSerial ?? "-",
                DeviceName = d.DeviceName ?? "-",
                UserName = d.UserName ?? "-",
                UserEmail = d.UserEmail ?? "-",
                OverallStatus = d.OverallStatus ?? "-",
                MigrationNotStarted = d.MigrationNotStarted.GetValueOrDefault(),
                MigrationInProgress = d.MigrationInProgress.GetValueOrDefault(),
                MigrationCompleted = d.MigrationCompleted.GetValueOrDefault(),
                MigrationFailed = d.MigrationFailed.GetValueOrDefault(),
                IntuneUnenrollment = d.IntuneUnenrollment.GetValueOrDefault(),
                AzureUnregister = d.AzureUnregister.GetValueOrDefault(),
                OutlookProfileRemoval = d.OutlookProfileRemoval.GetValueOrDefault(),
                OneDriveUnlink = d.OneDriveUnlink.GetValueOrDefault(),
                UserConfirmation = d.UserConfirmation.GetValueOrDefault(),
                UserReRun = d.UserReRun.GetValueOrDefault(),
                SleepSetting = d.SleepSetting.GetValueOrDefault(),
                M365SignOut = d.M365SignOut.GetValueOrDefault(),
                TeamsSignOut = d.TeamsSignOut.GetValueOrDefault(),
                ForesnsitTool = d.ForesnsitTool ?? "-",
                ComputerMigration = d.ComputerMigration.GetValueOrDefault(),
                LastUpdatedTime = d.LastUpdatedTime ?? DateTime.MinValue,
                WaveNumber = d.WaveNumber ?? "-"
            }).ToList();
 
            return View(sanitizedDevices);
        }
 
        // Existing Privacy action
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
 
        // Existing Error action
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
}

This is my model class:
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 
namespace Device_Migration_Admin_Portal.Models
{
    public class DeviceMigrationStatus
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string DeviceSerial { get; set; }
 
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
 
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
 
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
 
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string OverallStatus { get; set; }
 
        public bool? MigrationNotStarted { get; set; }
        public bool? MigrationInProgress { get; set; }
        public bool? MigrationCompleted { get; set; }
        public bool? MigrationFailed { get; set; }
        public bool? IntuneUnenrollment { get; set; }
        public bool? AzureUnregister { get; set; }
        public bool? OutlookProfileRemoval { get; set; }
        public bool? OneDriveUnlink { get; set; }
        public bool? UserConfirmation { get; set; }
        public bool? UserReRun { get; set; }
        public bool? SleepSetting { get; set; }
        public bool? M365SignOut { get; set; }
        public bool? TeamsSignOut { get; set; }
 
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ForesnsitTool { get; set; }
 
        public bool? ComputerMigration { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }
        public string WaveNumber { get; set; }
    }
}

I get this error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
lambda_method10(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Device_Migration_Admin_Portal.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in HomeController.cs
var devices = await _context.DeviceMigrationStatus.ToListAsync();

I am expecting to handle null values in C# application by replacing it default or specific values.
I will be thankful for any help.

Please read this and edit your question accordingly. Reproducible may be difficult when dealing with a database but you can do a far better job of attempting minimal. There's loads of code there that is irrelevant to the issue and it just makes it harder for us to identify where and what the issue is.

Hi @jmcilhinney, I made the changes and removed irrelevant code.

Which .NET (Core) version you are using? Suspect that could be due to the Nullable reference type enable in your project. <Nullable>true</Nullable>in .csproj file. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70068051/string-is-not-nullable-by-default-in-entity-framework-core-6-0

@YongShun, it worked I just removed <Nullable>true</Nullable> in .csproj file  , also my core version was 6.0, thanks

when creating sanitized devices use ?. instead of only dot (.)

Your DeviceMigrationStatus entity type has public string DeviceName { get; set; }, but in the DB it is nullable: should be public string? DeviceName { get; set; }. That was the first property I checked.... so likely more.

@Richard Is a string not always nullable in c# ?

Not if nullable is enabled (and this is the default in new project templates): see @YongShun's comment.
